# Transfer GTM and GA set ups from one account to another

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is it possible to transfer GTM and GA set ups from one account to another?

For example, I developed a GTM with GA tracking for the website. Now I would like to set up it for someone else. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the GTM container:

1. In the top navigation, click Admin.
2. In the Container section, click Export Container.
3. Click Choose a version or workspace.
4. Select the desired container or workspace version.
5. Click Download.

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106997?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. Can I do the same for GA?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.